# Check if element is contained in an array

Tags: c#

I have the following code, in which I want to verify if the the string called value matches an element contained in stringArray.

```
 string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };

        string value = "text1";

        if ( /* ______________ */) // if value exists in stringArray
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("False");
```

Is there a method I could use to execute this?

Comment: Your question may be voted down too due to amount of effort shown to search for possible solution. Please consider it for future questions.

Answer (score 3):

[`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) will do the work:

```
using System.Linq;

if (stringArray.Contains("text1")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
```

Comment: Btw this needs Linq referenced and `using System.Linq;` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work:

```
string[] stringArray = {"text 1", "text 2"};
string value = "text 1";
Console.WriteLine(stringArray.Any(str => str.Equals(value)) ? "True" : "False");
```